# MERGE table by ID with values from VALUES keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple quite static table:

```
SELECT [Id], [Order] FROM [Permissions]
```

returns

```
Id  Order
1   4
2   5
4   6
8   7
16  8
32  9
64  2
128 3
256 0
512 1
```

I have to make some changes in ordering like that:

```
SELECT pid, ord FROM 
(values (256, 0),(512, 1),(1, 2), (2, 3), (64, 4),(128, 5),(4, 6), (8, 7), (16, 8),(32, 9))
AS NewOrder(pid, ord)
```

I need to update ordering in the table `Permissions`.

I think MERGE statement would be a right choice.
But I can't find *simplest minimal example* of MERGE with `Id` syntax even in SO.

Question is How to merge table with data from `VALUES` keyword by `Id`?

Comment: What's your Expected output?

Comment: Edited post. Need to update ordering in source table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just updating the order of existing permissions (i.e. you are not inserting any additional permissions), you would simply use an `UPDATE` statement.

For example:

```
UPDATE
    Permissions AS pe

SET
    pe.Order = upd.Order

FROM
    (
        VALUES  
         ( 1, 1)
        ,( 2, 2)
        ,( 4, 3)
        ,( 8, 4)
        ,(16, 5)

    ) AS upd(Id, Order)

WHERE
    pe.Id = upd.Id
```

Comment: Thanks for the *realy* simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY**: I think simple `UPDATE` query is enough to achieve the desired output.

```
create table #permission(id int, Eorder int)
insert into #permission values
(1,4),
(2,5),
(4,6),
(8,7),
(16,8),
(32,9),
(64,2),
(128,3),
(256,0),
(512,1)

UPDATE p SET  p.Eorder = n.norder FROM(
    SELECT * FROM 
    (VALUES (256, 0),(512, 1),(1, 2), (2, 3), (64, 4),(128, 5),(4, 6), (8, 7), (16, 8),(32, 9)) x (id, norder)) n
INNER JOIN #permission p ON n.id = p.id
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
id  Eorder
1   2
2   3
4   6
8   7
16  8
32  9
64  4
128 5
256 0
512 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a solution using MERGE syntax, here's a query for you with 
  <kbd>[live demo](http://rextester.com/GIFZ68990)</kbd>

```
;
MERGE Permissions target 
USING 
(
   SELECT pid, ord FROM 
        (values (256, 0),(512, 1),(1, 2), (2, 3), (64, 4),(128, 5),(4, 6), (8, 7), (16, 8),(32, 9))
   AS NewOrder(pid, ord)   
) source  
  ON (target.id = source.pid)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
        UPDATE SET [Order] = ord  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (id, [Order])  
    VALUES (pid, ord);
```

Comment: Thank you for live demo. Quite simple example of `merge` statement, nothing extra.

Comment: @ApceHHypocrite Please do remember that for large data set MERGE is slower than INSERT UPDATE combination. However it is a terse syntax for INSERT and UPDATE, and forces us to think about INSERT cases and not only UPDATE.